# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tensorflow, pip

I installed the latest version of Python `(3.6.4 64-bit)` and the latest version of `PyCharm (2017.3.3 64-bit)`. Then I installed some modules in PyCharm (Numpy, Pandas, etc), but when I tried installing Tensorflow it didn't install, and I got the error message:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement TensorFlow (from versions: )
>       No matching distribution found for TensorFlow.

Then I tried installing TensorFlow from the command prompt and I got the same error message.
I did however successfully install tflearn.

I also installed Python 2.7, but I got the same error message again. I googled the error and tried some of the things which were suggested to other people, but nothing worked (this included installing Flask).

How can I install Tensorflow? Thanks.

Comment: what is your OS ?

Comment: @TheTechGuy Windows 10

Comment: @FlyingTeller the newest version

Comment: Try The process I have answered. I am assuming you already have Pip and Configured python in the ecosystem

Comment: @TheTechGuy I am not just asking how to install a module. I need help solving this error I am getting.

Comment: I am on Windows 10 with python 3.8.0 installed. Getting the same error message.

Comment: If you are on Apple Silicon with M1 chip or higher you need to install Tensorflow differently than how is outlined on the site currently. Instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73665921/2057171

Comment: I am on windows 10, python 3.11.1 and am getting the same error message. I have a 64-bit system and am getting this same error.

Comment: Python 3.11.0 and Windows-10 try to install in a virtual environment ....but it is showing same error.

Answer (score 265, accepted):

The latest requirements for running TensorFlow are documented in the [installation documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip).

- TensorFlow only supports 64-bit Python
- TensorFlow only supports certain versions of Python (for example, Python 3.6 is not supported)

So, if you're using an out-of-range version of Python (older or newer) or a 32-bit version, then you'll need to use a different version.

Comment: Could you please provide some references of where you have retrieved this information / date ?

Comment: on the official site, they still refer both 3.5.x and 3.6.x https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

Comment: v3.6.8 raises the same exception

Comment: Python v3.6.8 does not raise the exception for me; v3.7 did

Comment: @AER, I had this problem as well.  I was running py3.6.8 32 bit... but tensorflow only works with 64 bit

Comment: As of 2020-03-20 the same, but just for the next version: Python is at 3.8, but tensorflow does only supports 3.7

Comment: Still true as of December 2020 -- downgrade to 3.8 and enjoy

Comment: Could you please add to your prominent answer that officially "TensorFlow 2 packages require a pip version >19.0", thus in many cases `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` is required (true both for Linux and Windows). For instance, after installing python3.8 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, my pip version was 9.0.1, which was the problem in my case.

Comment: Adding to @Pedro 's comment:
Even though the documentation says that pip >19.0 is required, on Windows, it worked for me only after upgrading to latest pip which is > 21.0

Comment: As of 2021-02-28: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66400534/3025289

Comment: What version should I istall?

Comment: I have python 3.9 and tensorflow is working on it.

Comment: I have python 3.8, 64bit, and I got this same error. So, I don't think this "solution" should be given the credit for actually solving the problem.

Answer (score 116):

> I installed it successfully by `pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl`

Comment: If you find conflict with use of tensorflow and python3, this page has advice on editing the reserved word 'async' in a file https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20690

Comment: @Anil Sah what it will be for windows... I'm having the same problem

Comment: it installed successfully! yes, but, won't run correctly. why?

Comment: this is the only option if youre using wsl2

Answer (score 84):

There are a few important rules to install Tensorflow:

- You have to install Python **x64**. It doesn't work with x86/32b and it gives the same error as yours.
- Python versions later than 3.8 and Python 3.8 requires TensorFlow 2.2 or later. Check for [supported Python versions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip).

For example, for TensorFlow 2.9, you can install **Python3.8.6-64bit** and it works like a charm. Check the latest information on the website.

Comment: You can check your architecture using `python -c "import sys; print(sys.version)"` or `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P')*8)"`

Comment: I have Python 3.8.5, the 64-bit version, and I get the error when trying to install `tensorflow>=1.15,<1.16`.

Comment: @nbro Python 3.8 requires TensorFlow 2.2 or later

Comment: @krenerd You should ask TensorFlow. They probably need to spend some time to make it compatible.

Answer (score 47):

if you are using **anaconda**, python 3.7 is installed by default, so you have to downgrade it to 3.6:

> conda install python=3.6

then:

> pip install tensorflow

it worked for me in Ubuntu.

Comment: This was my problem. Needed to rollback the python version. Took half a day to figure out. The internet is full of guides that say nothing about this. And Conda can't give a meaningful error message? How many man hours are getting wasted globally on this python package crap.,FFS.

Answer (score 38):

I am giving  it for **Windows**

**If you are using python-3**

1. Upgrade pip to the latest version using `py -m pip install --upgrade pip`
2. Install package using `py -m pip install <package-name>`

**If you are using python-2**

1. Upgrade pip to the latest version using `py -2 -m pip install --upgrade pip`
2. Install package using `py -2 -m pip install <package-name>`

**It worked for me**

Comment: You have writen "python-2" twice, I guess the first one should be python 3.

Comment: Worked for me, too

Comment: doesn't work for me :( I just installed the latest Python 3.7 too

Comment: this fix worked for me with python3 on ubuntu

Comment: it is the same to my case, it is necessary to upgrade pip first

Answer (score 18):

[Tensorflow 2.2.0 supports Python3.8](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33374#issuecomment-613553319)

First, **make sure to install Python 3.8 64bit**. For some reason, the official site defaults to 32bit. Verify this using `python -VV` (two capital `V`, not `W`). Then continue as usual:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install wheel  # not necessary
python -m pip install tensorflow
```

As usual, make sure you have CUDA 10.1 and CuDNN installed.

Comment: Are you sure this would install a _release candidate_ (in this case `2.2.0rc3`)?

Comment: Yes, I am sure, I just did it. `assert tensorflow.__version__ == '2.2.0-rc3'` passes. Why the downvote?

Comment: I'm suprised. I get `2.1.0`. Is there maybe a `--pre` in a _pip_ configuration file somewhere?

Comment: I've performed a clean installation - no special configurations, nothing. Uninstall everything, install Python3.8.2.

Comment: Does specifying the version explicitly work
 for you?

Comment: I'm not trying to install tensorflow myself, I just want to point out (to other readers) that as far as I know _pip_ does not install _release candidates_ by default, unless the `--pre` option is used. I'm surprised that the _release candidate_ is getting installed in your case, maybe check the output of `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip config list`. But maybe I missed something entirely. If it works for you, then all is good.

Comment: I see what you mean, but picking a release candidate when there's no stable version available for 3.8 seems logical. `pip config list` gives me nothing. I will suggest using `--pre` in the answer.

Comment: Ah, that could explain it. If the only release compatible with the Python interpreter is a _release candidate_, then _pip_ might want to pick it anyway (I was testing with a different Python version `<3.8`). Still surprising to me.

Comment: Updated: no longer RC

Comment: This worked for me. I used python3.7 and tensorflow==2.0.3

Answer (score 14):

Tensorflow isn't available for `python 3.8` (as of Dec 4th 2019) according to their [documentation page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33374). You will have to downgrade to `python 3.7`.

Comment: It is available with python 3.8.2-64 bit version now (as of March 22 2020)

Answer (score 14):

## Apple Silicon (M1+ Chip)

If you are using a Mac with an M1 chip or higher, you need to install Tensorflow metal plugin for compatability with your architecture.

Simple installation instructions for Tensor Flow are found on Apple's website: https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin

*And since links tend to break in the future, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20230314181731/https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/) is an archive.*

Answer (score 13):

I am using python 3.6.8, on ubunu 18.04, for me the solution was to just upgrade pip

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install tensorflow==2.1.0
```

Comment: upgrade pip did it for me! Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Uninstalling Python and then reinstalling solved my issue and I was able to successfully install TensorFlow.

Answer (score 9):

So here's the message that I got on a M1 Pro while I was executing

> python -m pip install tensorflow-macos

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I then **re-installed python** from the **official source**:

https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/

*(Yes, as stupid as it seems.)*

I then followed the **Apple tutorial for Monterey**:

https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/

Everything was **solved** by then.

Comment: Save my day, thumbs up

Comment: You welcome, happy to know i helped someone today :)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to run this without having to re-install python, by running the script in the instructions an env is created with python 3.9.13. I was originally using python 3.10 with home-brew and everything ran just fine.

Comment: Happy to hear this! I needed both steps in my situation.

Answer (score 8):

Python version is not supported
Uninstall python

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-362/

You should check and use the exact version in install page.
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

python 3.6.2 or python 3.5.2 solved this issue for me

Answer (score 7):

(as of Jan 1st, 2021)

Any over version 3.9.x there is no support for TensorFlow 2. If you are installing packages via pip with 3.9, you simply get a "package doesn't exist" message. After reverting to the latest 3.8.x. Thought I would drop this here, I will update when 3.9.x is working with Tensorflow 2.x

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the problem is with Python 3.8. Use Python 3.7 instead. Steps I took to solve this.

- Created a python 3.7 environment with conda
- List item Installed rasa using pip install rasa within the environment.

Worked for me.

Comment: as of 2-2020, this may be the most likely answer.  It was for me.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem on my macOS (with M1 Pro) even with the latest 64-bit Python and the latest pip installed. This is how I've solved it. Try to run:

```bash
pip install tensorflow-macos
```

If you will get the error ending like this (like I did)...

```bash
...
raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

...then simply run:

```
pip install --default-timeout=100 tensorflow-macos
```

Answer (score 4):

**For python 3.12 tensorflow is not available yet**

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: 
none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

**Please be informed that TensorFlow is just available till `Python 3.11` as of 26th March 2024**

https://www.tensorflow.org/install

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Running this before the `tensorflow` installation solved it for me:

```
pip install "pip>=19"
```

As the [**`tensorflow`**'s system requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?lang=python3#system-requirements) states:

> pip 19.0 or later

Answer (score 3):

**For version TensorFlow 2.2:**

1. Make sure you have python 3.8

try:
`python --version`

or
`python3 --version`

or
`py --version`

2. Upgrade the pip of the python which has version 3.8

try:
`python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

or
`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

or
`py -m pip install --upgrade pip`

3. Install TensorFlow:

try:
`python3 -m pip install TensorFlow`

or `python -m pip install TensorFlow`

or `py -m pip install TensorFlow`

4. Make sure to run the file with the correct python:

try:
`python3 file.py`

or `python file.py`

or `py file.py`

Comment: This works. Try to find the combination that matches your system

Answer (score 2):

1.Go to  https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip   website and look if the version you are using support the Tensorflow. some latest version does not support Tesnsorflow. until Tensorflow releases its latest version for that Python version.

2. you must have 64 bit python installed
3. have latest version of pip installed
   pip install --upgrade pip

Answer (score 2):

using `pip install tensorflow --user` did it for me

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow seems to need special versions of tools and libs.
Pip only takes care of python version.

To handle this in a professional way (means it save tremendos time for me and others)
you have to set a special environment for each software like this.

An advanced tool for this is conda.

I installed Tensorflow with this commands:

sudo apt install python3

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 1

sudo apt install python3-pip

sudo apt-get install curl

curl https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh > Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh

bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh

yes

source ~/.bashrc

- installs its own phyton etc

nano .bashrc

- maybe insert here your proxies etc.

conda create --name your_name python=3

conda activate your_name

conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow

- check everything went well

python -c "import tensorflow as tf; tf.enable_eager_execution(); print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random_normal([1000, 1000])))"

PS: some commands that may be helpful
conda search tensorflow

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

uses virtualenv. Conda is more capable. Miniconda ist sufficient; the full conda
is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

use python version 3.6 or 3.7 but the important thing is you should install the python version of 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Docker, make sure you have

`FROM python:x.y.z`

instead of

`FROM python:x.y.z-alpine`.

Answer (score 0):

This issue also happens with other libraries such as matplotlib(which doesn't support `Python > 3.9` for some functions) let's just use COLAB.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different issue for me but I will still post an answer here. tensorflow package is working, but not tflite-runtime.

```
pip install --extra-index-url https://google-coral.github.io/py-repo/ tflite-runtime==2.5.0
```

Answer (score -2):

I solved the same problem with python 3.7 by installing one by one all the packages required

Here are the steps:

1. Install the package
2. See the error message:

   > couldn't find a version that satisfies the requirement -- the name of the module required
3. Install the module required.
   Very often, installation of the required module requires the installation of another module, and another module - a couple of the others and so on.

This way I installed more than 30 packages and it helped. Now I have tensorflow of the latest version in Python 3.7 and didn't have to downgrade the kernel.