# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow for python 3.6.7

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python --version
Python 3.6.7

C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip3 list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        10.0.1
setuptools 39.0.1

C:\WINDOWS\system32>PATH
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\HighTec\toolchains\tricore\v4.9.1.0-infineon-1.1\bin;C:\HighTec\licensemanager;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\WebEx\Productivity Tools;C:\Program Files\Micro Focus\StarTeam SDK 16.0\lib;C:\Program Files\Micro Focus\StarTeam SDK 16.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;c:\users\snaglapu\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\;C:\Users\snaglapu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Users\snaglapu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\;C:\Users\snaglapu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\snaglapu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

C:\WINDOWS\system32>py -m pip install --upgrade pip
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001A3A6CDFC50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001A3A6CDFDD8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001A3A6CDFD68>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001A3A6CDF160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001A3A6CDFEB8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/pip/
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\snaglapu\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (10.0.1)

C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F1F7B99470>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/tensorflow/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F1F7BCD4E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/tensorflow/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F1F7BCD588>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/tensorflow/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F1F7BCD7B8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/tensorflow/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F1F7BCD2B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/tensorflow/

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

I am trying to install tensorflow on top of python 3.6.7. I am getting the above mentioned error message. What could be the problem? I uninstalled python 3.6.5 and reinstalled 3.6.7.Also, tried upgrading pip.Both of them didn't work for me.I tried every possible solutions mentioned in the following link. [Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720833/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-tensorflow)

```
 C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip install --upgrade pip --proxy http://snaglapu:******** @<Proxy_name>:<port>--user
Collecting pip
 Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/d7/90f34cb0d83a6c5631cf71dfe64cc1054598c843a92b400e55675cc2ac37/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 819kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-18.1

C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip list
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\snaglapu\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "c:\users\snaglapu\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\snaglapu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'main'

after running the code behind the proxy error is popping when trying to read pip3 version or read the list of pip3

Comment: remove the `--upgrade`. This is used to upgrade a package you already have.

Comment: also are you behind a proxy?

Comment: and still the result is the same.

Comment: Yes I am behind a proxy

Comment: then you need `py -m pip install --proxy http://<user>:<password>@<proxyserver>:<port> tensorflow --user` or contact your system admin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using pip behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy)

Comment: I tried doing the changes. pip3 and tensorflow are updaed and installed. Now it is not possible to read list or version of pip3

Comment: `py -m pip list`. Do some googling around. Everything is possible..

Comment: Thanks a lot...!!