# Error specifying Python pip requirements.txt greater than, but less than

Tags: python, docker, pip

In my `requirements.txt`, I have the following:

```
tensorflow>=1.13.1,<2.0.0
```

When I run `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`, I am getting the following error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow<2.0.0,>=1.13.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: none)
>   ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow<2.0.0,>=1.13.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
>   The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r requirements.txt     && pip3 install src/' returned a non-zero code: 1

How can I specify that I need tensorflow less than 2.0.0, but greater than 1.13.1?

I'm running this inside a `docker build` command, so I'm starting with a fresh environment each time. I'm using the `python:latest` base image to build off of.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720833/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-tensorflow

Comment: `python:latest` as of today contains Python 3.8.0. Tensorflow support up to 3.7 at the moment.

Comment: Why not start from the official TF images, listed at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker?

Comment: I've already seen that. It doesn't mention Docker anywhere. Can you be more specific with what you're recommending?

Comment: @KlausD. I'm looking at the install documentation for TensorFlow, and don't see mention of specific Python versions. Where are you seeing that?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#data https://hub.docker.com/_/python?tab=tags

Comment: @KlausD perfect, thanks. I see that on the PyPi metadata now.

Comment: Seen what? The post @Waket linked? Why should it need to mention Docker, the point is to check the interpreter support *whatever* the environment.