# Thonny : installing tensorflow and importing it

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, data-science, thonny

I am having trouble importing and installing tensorflow. I can't install it via that Thonny manage package option nor via the command window for windows operators. I get the same error for both ways:

**ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none) Error: No matching distribution found for tensorflow**

I tried to convert back to python 3.6 but the issue still arises. This is annoying me because I cannot implement Machine Learning, which is something I am strongly passionate on.

Any reasons or solutions would be appreciated

Comment: You need to install separate 64-bit Python and direct Thonny to use it (Run => Select Interpreter)

Answer (score 0):

There are two important rules to install Tensorflow:

- You have to install Python **x64**. It doesn't work on 32b and it gives the same error as yours.
- It **doesn't** support the latest version of Python3 = 3.8.

For example, you can install **Python3.6.2-64bit** and it works like a Charm.

Took from:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53184758/11962645

Comment: TensorFlow does support Python 3.7, what it does not support is the current latest version of Python, which is 3.8 (not 3.7).

Comment: Edited version to 3.8

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow can be installed in Thonny by
`Tools -> Open System Shell`

`pip install --upgrade tensorflow`

Answer (score 0):

I use Thonny and the way to install it is

tool>>Open system shell
Then type in "pip3.6 install --upgrade TensorFlow"

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got Tensorflow version 2.5.0 to install and import using python version 3.6.8, with Thonny version 3.3.7, on a windows 10 laptop;-

When I installed Thonny, the default python interpreter was set to python 3.7.9. I need to change that, as follows;-
Using Thonnys menus and options , use tools / options / interpreter . Use the pull down option selections to find the python 3.6.8 that must have been previously installed on your machine. On my machine it is located at C:\Users\XXXX\ApplicationData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
Hit Ok and Thonny will show that it is now using python 3.6.8 in the lower shell !
Then install tensorflow using the Thonny menu tools / manage packages.
I installed tensorflow version 2.5.0 without any problems !
Then, in the interactive shell, I tested it ;-

Python 3.6.8 (C:\Users\con_o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe)

> > > import tensorflow
> > > 2021-05-20 09:06:01.231885: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
> > > 2021-05-20 09:06:01.258437: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.

> > > print(tensorflow.version)
> > > <module 'tensorflow._api.v2.version' from 'C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\version\**init**.py'>

> > > print(tensorflow.**version**)

2.5.0

Note;- The last command print(tensorflow.**version**) does NOT work without the previous command print(tensorflow.version) being run first !!

Note;- I could only install version 2.5.o of tensorflow. Thonny could not install any earlier version of Tensorflow!

I hope this helps the many folk struggling with the very difficult Tensorflow installations.