# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, manjaro

When i execute the command in my terminal

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

i get an error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

There was a similiar question in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720833/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-tensorflow). The cause for this error is that tensorflow supports only up to Python 3.7. So i checked my version

```
python3 --version3
--> 3.8.1
```

I tried to downgrade it with

```
 conda install python=3.7

 ---> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
 Solving environment: done

 # All requested packages already installed.
```

but it does not work. How can this be?

I am using manjaro as a distro.

Answer (score 0):

Could the Python3.7 you're running be the 32-bit version? Tensorflow requires the 64-bit version of python.