# Installing TensorFlow 1.15

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I've been trying to install **TensorFlow version 1** and It does not seem to exist anymore.
My project requires TensorFlow v1 and cannot use v2

```
pip install tensorflow==1.15
```

this returns

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15 (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3,
2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0) ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.15
```

**how can I install this specific version?**

Comment: Please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720833/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-tensorflow

Comment: You might need python3, and might be using python2

Answer (score 12):

```
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

This solution worked for me

Answer (score 3):

According to [this tensorflow github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39768) newer versions of python does not support older versions of tensorflow. Max version of python that has tensorflow 1.15 is 3.7

Answer (score 2):

upgrade pip to the latest version (19.0.1) work for my case.

> python -m pip install --upgrade pip