# tensorflow installation in python 3.9.0(64 bit) and pip version 20.2.3 .?

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, tensorflow2.0

[image]

I want to install TensorFlow, I have tried everything from reinstalling everything to trying different versions it doesn't help.

I have tried it with python 3.9.0 and pip version 20.0.3

Comment: Could you not just paste the output and remove the image ? It is hard to see.

Comment: Are you using anaconda ? Otherwise the 'anaconda' tag can be removed.

Comment: Mostly duplicate of [python - Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720833/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-tensorflow)

Answer (score 10):

Currently (1st of March, 2021), there is **no official stable** tensorflow version for the latest stable python 3.9.

However, **nightly version** of tensorflow supports python 3.9.

Simply `pip install tf-nightly-gpu` or `pip install tf-nightly`

---

Note, the library name is the same, e.g. importing works as `import tensorflow as tf` without any problems. This means you will not have to update your code once official support is added and you've migrated to the stable version.

Answer (score 3):

The [Official TensorFlow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install) specifies python 3.5-3.8.

You need to create a new environment as suggested in the previous answer with a new version of python, or uninstall python 3.9 and install other version. I use python 3.6.8 for Tensorflow and it works great.

Answer (score -1):

I had the similar problem but I am able to resolve it by downloading the python version 3.8.6 and installing it. Please pay attention to add the python and the respective pip path in the environment.

Then give the command, which will install tensorflow version 2.3.1

```
pip install tensorflow
```

You may upgrade the pip by following command,

```
py -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

I hope that it works for you.