# Installing Tensorflow on Mac OS Big Sur with pip

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, python-3.8, macos-big-sur

**System used:**

```
MacOS Big Sur MacBook Air M1 processor - 
Python 3.8.2 - 
pip 20.3.3
```

I am trying to install `Tensorflow 2` on my Mac, I  have all the requirements needed, I tried

`python -m pip install tensorflow` but I receive these two errors:

> > ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
> >  ERROR: No matching distribution
> > found for tensorflow

I also tried to download from https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.4.0/#files the last release for mac and python 3.8 and running `python -m pip install /Users/v.b./Downloads/tensorflow-2.4.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl`

I receive this error:

> ERROR: tensorflow-2.4.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl is not a
> supported wheel on this platform.

I think it is something really stupid I am missing but I don't know what it is. I googled a lot and some other people found a solution to similar problems but not exactly to mine. Does anyone have any clue or had the same issue ?

Comment: Could you set up an Anaconda environment ? That is [easier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64622401/tensorflow-installation-in-python-3-9-064-bit-and-pip-version-20-2-3/64623488#64623488).

Comment: no I need to run the command using the terminal as I use spider standalone, without anaconda (faster and lighter than installing the entire anaconda app)

Comment: The tensorflow are still on alpha versions & might take some more time to become available as beta releases (which is much more stable). Mean while you can have a look at this https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/releases and watch this issue https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/46

Answer (score 1):

Check this one: https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos

Once downloaded you may use install_venv.sh to install tf with virtual environment.

Or install it to your current setup by running the command below:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade ~/Downloads/tensorflow_macos/x86_64/*.whl --no-dependencies --force
```