# Problems installing tensorflow on Windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

i have been trying to install TensorFlow on my Win10 machine using pip, I have never had a problem using pip before but for some reason when I run `pip install tensorflow` with pip version `21.0.1` I get the following error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I have tried to install using the `--user` tag but same problem occurs, i got the install command from the official website `https://www.tensorflow.org/install`,

if anyone knows what is causing pip to think the package doesn't exist any help appreciated.

Comment: Which python version do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tensorflow supports only Python 3.5-3.8 versions. That might cause a problem.
You can read more at a similar post about that error; [Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720833/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-tensorflow)

I suggest you to use virtual environments created with Conda.
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/

If you use Conda, you can specify required Python version, pip libraries to that env and use it from anywhere  in your OS.