# Installing TensorFlow Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I am trying to install tensorflow, but when I run

```
pip install tensorflow
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

In many other posts the solution is to upgrade the pip version. But mine already is version 21.1.1 and I still can not install tensorflow in my env..

What am I missing?

Comment: What is your version of Python (`python -V`)? Have you checked the requirements here https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip ?

Comment: yes I meet the requirements. Python 3.6.9, pip 21.1.1, Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? (you should add more informations in your question too: what platform etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
pip install ISR --no-deps
```

However, have you used conda? It's really easy to install Tensorflow using it. Just

```
 conda install Tensorflow
```

(if you don't have it install from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart))

Best Regards, ykostov

Answer (score 1):

You may be using python3 instead of python 2, if so try:

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

Comment: my python version is 3.6.9
but even when I run it with pip3, the same error occurs.

Comment: i read another article about your problem and found out tensorflow only supports 64bit version of python. This may be the case

Comment: You can check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720833/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-tensorflow

Comment: I'm running on 64-bit

Comment: try this: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: btw, have you tried `pip3.6 install tensorflow`? Just checking