# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15 (Windows Terminal)

Tags: python, bash, tensorflow, terminal, conda

[Instructions from Supervisor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PTRA.png)
I am very new to Python and BashCode. My supervisor wants me to run code from a GitHub repository. I have cloned the repository from GitHub. Now he asks to create a virtual environment with anaconda packages installed. I downloaded Miniconda and using the conda command (the command is on the attached image). Now, the next step is to execute the following: "pip install -r requirements.txt" in the repository. I tried, but I receive the error that is in title. I tried "pip install tensorflow==1.15" but that does not work. I am very confused on what to do. Thank you. I am using Windows terminal

Comment: Tensorflow only supports Python 3.5 to 3.8, what is your version of python?

Comment: Python 3.10.4. If this is the issue, I tried to create a virtual environment with python 3.7 and it still did not work. Do you recommend downloading an earlier version of python?

Comment: see that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720833/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-tensorflow

Comment: and use pip3 instead pip

Comment: I don't see how the question would be related to bash, so I would remove the bash-tag. If you think different, you should at least - since you are on Windows - specify which implementation of version you are using (i.e. WSL, Cygwin, git-bash, ....)

Answer (score 0):

To install TensorFlow 1.15, Python version should be 3.5-3.7. Python 3.10 only supports the latest tensorflow releases Tensorflow version = 2.8, 2.9

Please [install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#package_location) the [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) version 3.7 which supports almost all the tensorflow version (>Tensorflow 1.13).

You can refer to this [tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu) details for more details.