# pip install tensorflow - no matching distribution

Tags: tensorflow, pip, wsl-2, miniconda

I am following [TensorFlow's installation guide for Windows 10 & WSL2](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip).

But I get the following when I finally get to the point of installing TensorFlow,

```
(base) root@SCEDWLWC164905:~# conda activate tf
(tf) root@SCEDWLWC164905:~# pip install tensorflow
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f445141b6a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f445141b9d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f445141bc40>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f445141bdf0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f445141bfd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/tensorflow/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
(tf) root@SCED:~# python --version
Python 3.9.16
(tf) root@SCED:~#
```

I set up the environment with Python 3.9 as recommended in the above link. I have followed all the NVIDIA driver prerequisites.

I had a look to see if `pip` was installed,

```
(tf) root@SCED:~# which pip
/root/miniconda3/envs/tf/bin/pip
```

It is, so what's the issue here?

EDIT :: There have been some suggestions that this is a Python version issue. I repeat, I am following Tensorflow's official documentation. They seem to be under the impression that Python 3.9 is the one to use - they'd know right? The answers linked to in the comments are badly out of date.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720833/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-tensorflow)

Comment: @AhmedSbai no I have been through that already. The official line is that TF supports Python 3.9 & most of those answers are out of date.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that Windows Subsystem for Linux existed. Back in my day, back before the war, we had to install TensorFlow in the snow uphill both ways with Anaconda for Windows! I was able to get Tensorflow GPU and CUDA working with Jupyter Notebooks recently using by installing Cygwin and adding it to my path env. You just have to install it in the Anaconda console because Windows can't get figure out how to use the right Python version.

Answer (score 0):

once pip installed, try this line?

```
python3 -m pip install --default-timeout=10000 tensorflow-macos
```