Cannot install required version of tensorflow-gpu
I am trying to install this Python package as per the instructions, resulting in this error: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==2.5.0 (from rascore) (from versions: 2.12.0) ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu==2.5.0.
I created a conda environment with Python 3.7 and installed RDKit, but at the final step to install the actual package I get the error.
I've also tried the installation in environments with Python 3.8, 3.9 and 3.12, as well as specifically trying to install tensorflow-gpu version 2.5.0, but result in the same error each time.
It seems like the required version of tensorflow-gpu is just not available to me. Is there a way around this?

Do you have an Nvidia gpu? If I am not mistaken hardware acceleration for tensorflow does not work with other brands of GPU

Also does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720833/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-tensorflow?rq=2

Hi @serax I have an Apple M1 chip which I believe has integrated gpu. On the post you sent I can see there are different instructions for installing tensorflow with MacOS (https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/) and it requires Python 3.8 or higher but the package I need requires Python 3.7, does that mean it won't be possible for me to install it on my Mac?

On the github page it says: "Create an environment (note: the python version must be == 3.7, 3.8): " so i guess that you could try installing both with python 3.8

I've tried now with an environment using Python 3.8 but still getting the same error from my post, only tensorflow-gpu version 2.12.0 is available

note that the package has not been "often"  updated (last 3 yrs ago!) and there were a lot of problems exactly with tensorflow and python3.7 back to then! probably you need to downgrade some other requirements
